# Modify .wrl color in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I'm importing .wrl data from FEA simulation, setting attribute to Col for rendering in Cycles Blender and see vertex color. I wisk to use Blender to better visulations results and animations. Is there any possibility to smoothing interfacing between color? Thanks.

My color render using Blender.
[image]

My idea of render.
[image]